# JavaScript error: 'moment' is undefined in Full Calendar Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery FullCalendar control in my ASP.Net MVC 5 application. I have followed the steps exactly as given in this tutorial 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

But am continously getting this error 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'moment' is undefined

I have not added any event. Just trying to load the calendar but getting this error when using FullCalendar v2.1.1. SAme works fine if I use FullCalendar v1.6.3

Is there any additional changes to be done like including scripts/css for v2.1.1?
Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like following sentence, You must need to include MomentJS

Moment objects are used throughout the API. A Moment object represents a point in time, like the native Date Object, but is far superior. **MomentJS is a third-party library that must be included on the same page as FullCalendar.**

[Reference](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying with momentjs libraries and let know if its working fine

Comment: It works. I had to include momentjs before fullcalendar. Thanks for your help :)